# PL SQL : Query to count differents values of a field

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have to do counts to the quantity of entitys in the database i have to obtain the quantity of registries for entities that appear

```
ENTITY OVERALL DATE HOUR
====== ===== ==== ====
ENT1 5 20100318 12:00
ENT2 20 20100318 12:00
ENT3 12 20100318 12:00

CURSOR1
SELECT distinct(rp.cod_entidad),
YYYYYYYYY,
to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') as fecha_pago,
to_char(sysdate,'hh-mi-ss') as hora_pago
FROM registry rp, product pc
where pc.nro_solicitud = rp.nro_solicitud
and pc.resp_2= 'OK'
and pc.resp_1= 'OK'
```

Comment: In case you hadn't realized: `select distinct(x), y...` does not mean that `distinct` is applied only to `x`. It is not a function. `distict` modifies the whole result set so that it contains only unique rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` on the column that you want to be unique.
In order for PL-SQL to not complain you'll have to use an aggregate function that will select a value for the other columns.
I've picked `MAX()`, but `MIN()` or the non-existent `whatever()` will do just as well.

```
SELECT 
  rp.cod_entidad,
  count(*) as rowcount,   -- number of rows per distinct rp.cod_entidad
  MAX(to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) as fecha_pago,
  MAX(to_char(sysdate,'hh-mi-ss')) as hora_pago
FROM registry rp
INNER JOIN product pc ON (pc.nro_solicitud = rp.nro_solicitud)
WHERE pc.resp_2 = 'OK' AND pc.resp_1 = 'OK'
GROUP BY rp.cod_entidad
```

**[Implicit where join considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-versus-where-clause-any-difference)**
P.S. please don't use that ugly implicit where join, it is confusing and bad practise, because you are mixing selection criteria with join criteria in your `where` clause for no reason whatsoever.
We've had explicit join syntax since 1993, I warmly recommend it.
It will make writing correct queries much much easier and it will make your intentions clearer.

Comment: I'd guess the `YYYYYYY` was a placeholder for the solution and should be replaced with `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select entity, sum(overall)
from registry
group by entity
order by entity
```

your question is difficult to understand...

Comment: i understand but my english is not good and more to explain this question, I have no column overall, I have to get the number of records per entity, this is the problem, thank you